# Sending picture with intent to TypeApp Mail

Tags: android, email, android-intent

When I try to send a picture using an intent with chooser it's working with gmail for example but not with an other mail client ([TypeApp](http://www.typeapp.com/)).

It's strange because when I try to share picture using other apps, it's working everywhere, include with the TypeApp mail client. Maybe they use an other extra type ?

Maybe the extra `EXTRA_STREAM` is not correct ?

This is my intent :

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                        "mailto",getIntent().getStringExtra("mail"), null));
                emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + filePath));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send a mail..."));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using `ACTION_SEND` and not `ACTION_SEND_TO` :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{getIntent().getStringExtra("mail")});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + filePath));
intent.setPackage("com.trtf.blue");
startActivity(intent);
```